# Increase fraction size in Google Docs equation

Tags: google-docs

Fractions in Google Docs equations are too small to read:

[image]

How can I write normal-sized fraction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ugly equation: 

Left side: one usage of equation builder. Increase font size.

Right side: use another instance of equation builder.

[image]

In this example, 30px on the left, 18px on the right. The formula writer tried to keep the box (container for formula) the same height as the rest of the line height; shrink to fit.

Comment: Thank you. It seems it not always work changing font for an existing equation.

Comment: If you make two equations it should work out visually for you. It really is one equation, but it's in two parts. The equation becomes an Object when you use the equation builder. The Object is shrunk down to fit the height of the Line and that's why the equation gets really small. So use two parts if only one side is a fraction.

Answer (score 7):

Select the **whole** equation box, and change font size normally

Comment: Doesn't this change the font size for the entire equation? That's probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: No really it does

Comment: You have to change the font size for the whole line that the equation is in. If you have text other than the equation in the same line, and try to only increase the font size for the equation, it won't work

Comment: Worked for me. The font of the whole equation is changed, but it looks that, now the font in the fraction matches the rest of the text.

Answer (score 1):

To change the size of the equation font you have to change the font size of the whole line that the equation is in

Answer (score 1):

#### Selecting the "whole equation"

I found this difficult to get right at first, so I am expanding on the accepted answer of @Omar Elrefaei.

[image]

At first I thought I was selecting the "whole equation" with the above selection, but changing the font size had no effect.

Then I realised I needed to expand the selection a *tiny bit* more. In my case, by pressing `SHIFT` `Right arrow`.

The highlighted area expanded *very slightly* (in my case, downwards) giving this appearance.
[image]

Now, adjusting the font size on the menu does indeed increase the font size of the equation.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. The tick mark means accepted, not correct. Ref [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)